# IntelliJ high CPU when open reactjs jsx file with export default class?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA high CPU when open ReactJS JSX file with "export default" in Laravel project.

When I not open that file, or I use only "export" (not "export default") it work fine.

Who can tell me why?

When use only export:

[image: When use only export]

When use export default:

[image: When use export default]

Comment: Inspections maybe. Open a profiler. Or just https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Thank for answer. I try turn on Power safe mode, and IntelliJ use low CPU.
I think the case is IntelliJ has somethink run for React.